# Can I get code to stop if a variable reaches zero?

Tags: python

I have been wanting to get into coding videogames, I am 15 and decided to try and start off making a text based game in python since I am not sure how to go about starting to make videogames (any advice on this would also be helpful :])

I was wondering if there was a way to get a program to stop if a variable reaches zero without having "if health == 0" everywhere in my code, should I use a while loop or is there another method I can use?

Comment: You can use a while loop. 

Comment: Without an example of what you tried so far, it is hard to recommend a way in particular.
You could run your code in a while loop (as mentioned by @JulianCamilleri) or handle health as a class which will trigger the end of the game when set to zero or using exception (like StopIteration for iterator)

Comment: `while health != 0` or (since non-zero numbers evaluate to True under boolean operator in python) `while health` sounds best.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
while(variable!=0):
    your statement
```

Using this you can run your code unless the variable reaches 0. Hope it helps. Happy coding :) champ!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As in your case you know the condition **(i == 0)** to stop iteration, **while loop** will be the best option to choose among other types of loops. Do consider using functions to make sure code reusability.

Refer to the below code snippet to avoid using `if health == 0`

```
health = 5
while health: 
  print(health)
  health -= 1
```

**Output:** 5 to 1